# How to close the material drawer with the change in the media screen size?

Tags: dart, angular-components, angular-dart, dart-webui

How do I change the visibility of drawer from persistent drawer to temporary drawer at the change of media screen. I want to implement the response of drawer as persistent `@media screen and (min-width: 701px)` and temporary `@media screen and (max-width: 700px)`. With the app_layout of angular_components in an Angular Dart project.

app_component.html

```
<material-drawer persistent #drawer="drawer"
    [class.custom-width]="customWidth"
    [attr.end]="end ? '' : null">
  <material-list *deferredContent>
    <div group class="mat-drawer-spacer"></div>
    <div group>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="inbox"></material-icon>Inbox
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Star
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="send"></material-icon>Sent Mail
      </material-list-item>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="drafts"></material-icon>Drafts
      </material-list-item>
    </div>
    <div group>
      <div label>Tags</div>
      <material-list-item>
        <material-icon icon="star"></material-icon>Favorites
      </material-list-item>
    </div>
  </material-list>
</material-drawer>
<div class="material-content">
  <header class="material-header shadow">
    <div class="material-header-row">
      <material-button icon
          class="material-drawer-button" (trigger)="drawer.toggle()">
        <material-icon icon="menu"></material-icon>
      </material-button>
      <span class="material-header-title">Simple Layout</span>
      <div class="material-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a>Link 1</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a>Link 2</a>
      </nav>
      <nav class="material-navigation">
        <a>Link 3</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ad erat postea ullamcorper nec, veri veniam quo
    et. Diam phaedrum ei mea, quaeque voluptaria efficiantur duo no. Eu adhuc
    veritus civibus nec, sumo invidunt mel id, in vim dictas detraxit. Per an
    legere iriure blandit. Veri iisque accusamus an pri.
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <h3>Options</h3>
    <material-toggle [(checked)]="end" label="end">
    </material-toggle>
    <material-toggle [(checked)]="customWidth" label="custom width">
    </material-toggle>
  </div>
</div>
```

app_component.dart

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/material_persistent_drawer.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/content/deferred_content.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_button/material_button.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_icon/material_icon.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_list/material_list_item.dart';
import 'package:angular_components/material_toggle/material_toggle.dart';

@Component(
  selector: 'mat-drawer-demo',
  directives: [
    DeferredContentDirective,
    MaterialButtonComponent,
    MaterialIconComponent,
    MaterialPersistentDrawerDirective,
    MaterialToggleComponent,
    MaterialListComponent,
    MaterialListItemComponent,
  ],
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  styleUrls: [
    'app_component.css',
    'package:angular_components/app_layout/layout.scss.css',
  ],
)
class AppComponent {
  bool customWidth = false;
  bool end = false;
}
```

app_component.scss

```
@import 'package:angular_components/app_layout/mixins';

:host {

}

.controls {
  align-items: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.custom-width {
  @include mat-drawer-width(50%);
  @include mat-temporary-drawer-width(50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 701px) {

}

@media screen and (max-width: 700px) {

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't only with CSS as they are separate Components and not only CSS things.

It may be possible to have two drawers that you ng-if depending on what the screensize is, but it isn't a pattern we support or plan to support. Sorry